# OpenLayers - Pre cache layers on Client

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, cache

We are using GeoServer and OpenLayers to display our data. We have a static WMS layer and several dynamic WFS layers. I want to use client side caching of the WMS layer at different pre-defined zoom levels.

When I first load the map I want the layers to display. The WMS layer will be client cached but then in the background I want the WMS layer for the next ZoomIn level  to cache also. Is this possible?

How much should we be caching i.e. how much is too much?

Also is there any point in caching dynamic WFS layers?

Any help appreciated.